# How is probability affected when the sample space is knowingly reduced?

Tags: probability

We were discussing poker probabilities, and this thing came up: Given that you have a flush draw (basically 4 of the 5 cards dealt are of the same suit) there are 9 outs and hence, the probability is given as 34.91%. This is calculated using:

$$
P = 1 - \left(\frac{47-outs}{47} \times \frac{46-outs}{46}\right)
$$

This however, does not account at all, for the cards that are dealt to other players. Which does make sense to some extent given that I, as an observer have no clue what they are, and for me, all of the 47 cards are equally likely.

Let's take another example. There are 10 balls, 5 of them red and 5 of them black. Now, a ball is picked up. The probability that it is red is 0.5 and the same goes for black. Now, a ball is removed and we don't know whether it was black or red. What is the probability of picking out a red ball now?

One way I can think is, that there are two cases: Either it was black or red that was removed. In the first case, where black was removed,

$$
P_b(red) = \frac{5}{9}
$$

and in the second case,

$$
P_r(red) = \frac{4}{9}
$$

Given that both have the same change of occurring, we get:

$$
P = \frac{P_r(red)}{2} + \frac{P_b(red)}{2}
  =\frac{5}{18} + \frac{4}{18} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Which is essentially the same which we got without this extra step. Clearly having knowledge changes the probability completely, which is

$$
P(red|removed=black) = \frac{5}{9}
$$

So, my question is, given that we don't know how exactly the sample space was reduced, but we do know the amount by which it was reduced, how is probability affected?

Comment: The ball math looks correct to me; it may seem counterintuitive, but that's probability for you. Maybe it helps conceptualizing it to keep in mind that probability is a measure of uncertainty.

Comment: This seems to rediscover conditional probability (and Bayes formula) from first principles. What is the question actually?